# Descending into JSON with nested for loops, poor practice?

Tags: json, algorithm

Is descending into nested dictionary's considered poor practice? Is there a faster more efficient way to do it?

The question is this. I currently have a result from a query where it returns in this structure:

```
-...
    -...
-Location
    -...
    -...
    -...
    -Continent
        -...
        -Country
            -...
            -State
                -...
                -City
-...
    -...
```

etc.

I need to run through this to check all cities. But nested for loops are bad right? I could traverse recursively but there are many values along side at each level that are unnecessary to traverse. I could store a list of keys and only descend into the next if it is in the list of keys. But that would require prior knowledge of countries / continents etc. in the tree.

With nested for loops this is easy. And as far as I can tell would be O(n) time (in relation to cities). It's never repeating loops it's never I know how to descend into it. BUT in some cases (remember this is just an example.) I end up with MANY nested for loops. Is there a cleaner way to do this? Am I wrong to assume that this is *essentially* O(n) time? It's only hitting each value at the the deepest level a single time, which seems essentially the same as running through a linear list of cities, however with the advantage that if we need the parent data it is only stored once as opposed to WITH each element.

But still. In my code it looks wrong, and it feels ridiculous. I'm sure this is something everyone has encountered at some point but am unable to really find any REAL content addressing this. Was wondering if there is some reasonable way to clean this up. Can I pull out only Cities and somehow flatten the data structure? Or is this totally OK the way it is. Ignore the fact that I don't particularly like the way it looks and just accept that it is as good as it gets.

Any input and alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: ask whoever is providing you the data to give it to you differently.

Comment: I really don't think there's much to worry about in terms of asymptotics. However, you may dislike the syntax of your search for cities; in that case, you might look into libraries like [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) that offer a convenient syntax for running simple queries on JSON.